# Access ECS repository from external account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I´m using ECS repository for two accounts, one for non_prod another for prod. The repo is part of the non_prod account

The problem that I found is, even giving access from the non_prod account repository to the prod account, the prod account cannot pull the docker image. And complains that the docker image does not exist.

Still I can access to the repository, but not pull the image since the prod account think, that does not exist

Obviously the image exist since it´s used in the non_prod environment.
Also I compare the ~/.docker/config.json credentials and are the same to connect to the ECS repo that I have on the non_prod account.

I even try the temporally dangerous give all access in the repo and still nothing. Any idea what´s wrong here?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

We are using the same setup in our environments and it works pretty fine for us. Make sure you are doing the following things:

1) While accessing the containers you are passing the --registryid parameter in the login command, essentially,

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --registry-ids <value here> | /bin/sh
```

2) You have given the access in the ECR repository for the prod account, essentially in the permission section of ECR repo, there is an entry in Prinicipal for arn:aws:iam:::root and correct permissions are there for push and pull operations.

Please let me know if you are doing both of these things and still not able to access the containers.